# PostgreSQL BIGSERIAL and "duplicate key" on insert

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

First I run

```
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (1);
```

After I run

```
INSERT INTO users (created_at) VALUES ('2016-11-10T09:37:59+00:00');
```

And I get

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

Why id sequence is not incremented when I insert "id" by myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `DEFAULT` clause only gets evaluated if you either omit the column in the `SET` clause or insert the special value `DEFAULT`.

In your first `INSERT`, the `DEFAULT` clause is not evaluated, so the sequence is not increased. Your second `INSERT` uses the `DEFAULT` clause, the sequence is increased and returns the value 1, which collides with the value explicitly given in the previous `INSERT`.

Don't mix `INSERT`s with automatic value creation using sequences and `INSERT`s that explicitly specify the column. Or if you have to, you sould make sure that the values cannot collide, e.g. by using even numbers for automatically generated values and odd numbers for explicit `INSERT`s.

Comment: better you explain with an example

Comment: @TejasTank The example is in the question.